# Java DOM parsing of XML- can't get attributes from child-child nodes

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I'm trying to parse an XML document using DOM parser in java. I need to get the values of various attributes. I'm trying to parse the following document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BirthResults>
    <Results>
        <Rejected>
            <Reject>
                <Birth Etg = "etg1"/>
                <Causes>
                    <Cause Code = "test1" Desc = "Desc1"/>
                </Causes>
            </Reject>
            <Reject>
                <Birth Etg = "etg2"/>
                <Causes>
                    <Cause Code = "test2" Desc = "Desc2"/>
                </Causes>
            </Reject>
        </Rejected>
    </Results>
</BirthResults>
```

Using the following code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Parsers {

    String Etg, Dob, Breed, Brd, Sex, EId, GdEtg, SuEtg, SiEtg, BLoc, BSLoc,
            PLoc, PSLoc, Code, Desc;
    static String response;

    public String Birth(InputStream in) {

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(in);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            try {
                NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("Reject");
                int L = list.getLength();

                for (int x = 0; x < L; x++) {

                    setNull();

                    Node node = list.item(x);
                    NodeList sublist = node.getChildNodes();

                    for (int y = 0; y < sublist.getLength(); y++) {
                        Node finNode = (Node) sublist.item(y);
                        if (finNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element fin = (Element) finNode;
                            getAttributes(fin);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    private void getAttributes(Element fin) {
        Etg = fin.getAttribute("Etg");
        Code = fin.getAttribute("Code");
        System.out.println(Etg + ":" + Code);
    }
}
```

Whilst I get the value for Etg out, the values for Code and Desc are returned as blank. I'm assuming this is because they're embedded on a deeper 'tier' but I have no idea how to get around the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NodeList sublist = node.getChildNodes();` assigns to sublist children, it means that there are assigned nodes: `Birth, Causes`. The `Causes` node contains list of children, so if your `finNode` is `Birth` element you can get `Egt` attr, but if `finNode` is `Causes` you have to get children and then you can read `Code` and `Desc` from each children of 'Causes'.

For checking name of element you can use `fin.getTagName()`