# How do I parse XML String as Objects with states?

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing, object

I have the followin code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;



        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());

Output:
"<?xml version="1.0"?><query id="19247955" amount="10" points="44"></query><query id="19247830" amount="3" points="44"></query>"
```

I want to parse it to Objects with such states as Id, Amount and Points. 
I tried to use "DOM and a StringReader", but tags are empty so I failed.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971183/java-dom-parsing-of-xml-cant-get-attributes-from-child-child-nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out java xml binding (jaxb) api (http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/ ), or another library that also works well is beanio (http://beanio.org/).

Is better to just use these once (maybe many more out there) than to take matters in ur own hands, they are meant to create java objects from xml files (i.e. to unmarshal or to deserialize) and xml files from java objects (i.e. marshaling /serializing).
Programming is more fun if you trying hard to apply solutions that result naturally...

Happy coding